# Laravel error paginating the data ( render method doesn't exist )

Tags: laravel, pagination

I am working on a project and I have Articles table and I get the data and show it in index page

the function

```
public function index()
{
    $articles = Article::paginate(10);

    return view('dashboard/news/index', compact('articles'));
}
```

the view

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
    <div class="row py-4">
        <div class="col-md-5 article-img">
            <img src="{{ asset('uploads/news-images') }}/{{ $article->img }}" class="w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 p-3 row flex-column justify-content-center">
            <h5 class="text-mine-blue">{{ $article->title }}</h5>
            <span class="text-muted my-2">{{ $article->created_at }}</span>
            <p>{!! \Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($article->content, 170, $end = '...') !!}</p>
            <div class="read-more-btn">
                <a href="{{ route('articles.show', $article->id) }}" class="btn text-light">
                    {{ __('اقرأ المزيد') }}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
{!! $articles->render() !!}
```

the AppServiceProvider

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

public function boot()
{
    Paginator::useBootstrap();
}
```

the error

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::render does not exist. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\aqaraty\resources\views\articles\index.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, how many articles in total? If total count less than your paginate count render function won’t do anything.
Also, you can try it with {!! $articles->render() !!}

Sorry, I’m writing from phone. I will edit my answer later.

Comment: I edited it but I am facing the same error